# How to exit & fail Test Method explicitly in C# MSTest

Tags: c#, mstest

I am automating test script using selenium c# where I am using MSTest framework to automate test.

My query is regarding test method. I want to exit & fail test method explicitly but I am not able to do that.

I have tried below methods but it only throws an exception but it did not fail that test method & not continued next test method.
can any one help me on this

```
Assert.Fail()
Assert.Inconclusive()
Enviroment.exit()
```

Regards,
Abhijit

Comment: `Assert.Fail()` will end the test with a `Failed` status for it and the framework will move to the next. Please explain what you mean that it did not fail the test. Will be helpful to see the test itself

Comment: @GiladGreen I have a helper method for failed test methods, where I close the driver and call "Assert.Fail()"
        public static void AssertFail()
        {
            SeleniumDriver.CloseWebDriver();
            Assert.Fail();            
        }

I want my test execution to stop once it hits this statement and continue to the next test method, but it is not. Need help in doing so.

Comment: ? So you want to stop all tests if one fails?